# Convert DB2 decimal to date & time then Calculate Mins between to dates & times

Tags: sql, db2

Sir i have 4 columns in decimal

datein

```
||    timein       ||  Dateout    || Timeout  || calculate_between_mintues 
-----------------------------------------------------------
20180501      || 093012      ||  20180501    || 103012 || ?
20180501      || 233013      ||  20180502    || 042012 || ?
```

how to calculate minutes between in date & time and out date & time

Comment: Why are you storing them as decimal, and not as timestamp?

Comment: old program in iSeries  storing in decimal

Comment: what Db2 version are you using? Db2 for i, Db2, Db2 for z/OS?  Also note the version number you are on

Comment: Db2 version 
DB2 i8

Comment: ...um, are these "local" date and times, not UTC?  Do you need to worry about daylight savings time?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the decimals to char, concat them and then make the difference of timestamps in minutes

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(4, CHAR(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(DATEOUT),TO_CHAR(TIMEOUT)),
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(DATEIN),TO_CHAR(TIMEIN)),
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')))
```

Comment: No, **absolutely not**.  The result of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is always an estimate, due to the imprecise nature of the subtraction result given to it; the answer _will be wrong_ if the difference is longer than one month.